# Autoplay a video on scroll with WordPress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, elementor

In advance, my apologies for my bad english.

I'm using WordPress with Elementor.
I wan't to have an autoplay on my video only when it is in viewport.

```
I've tried this code :
```

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

```
//To check if element is visible
function checkVisible(elm) {
    var rect = elm.getBoundingClientRect();
    var viewHeight = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight);
    return !(rect.bottom < 0 || rect.top - viewHeight >= 0);
}

//To play-pause self-hosted videos in elementor only when it's visible
$(window).scroll(function () {
    $(".elementor-video").each(function (i, obj) {
        if (checkVisible(obj)) {
            obj.play();
        } else
            obj.pause();
    });
});
```

});

```
It's works BUT ONLY if the user has already click on play.
How to improve this ?

In advance, thanks.
```

Comment: As you mentioned in another comment, you will not be able to autoplay a video with sound. Every browser will prevent that.

Comment: This functionality is blocked for a reason, because it's objectively a terrible user experience for videos to automatically start without the user's explicit go-ahead. This is the case for all recent versions of all major user agents. If there is a workaround, you can expect it to be patched in the future. **In short - what you are asking for is not possible *by design.***

Answer (score 0):

Browsers do not allow autoplay for video when is not muted.

Comment: You're right.
It's work with mute by default but I need sound. How I do this ?

Comment: I'm not sure if you can do that. But you can try first autoplay video and then unmuted it with javascript. But I didn't try it yet so I don't no if this will be working.

Comment: What is the code to unmuted in javascript please ?

Comment: I found it and I tried, but unfortunately, it's blocked again ...

Answer (score 0):

Well i will prefer keeping it simple. Below I have mentioned the complete process and will be adding the image as well to make it simple for you. This is from a [st courier tracking website](https://anycouriertracking.com/st-courier-tracking/) which is displaying tracking results and showing it to the customers so whenever the customer comes the video is auto played . How are they doing it.

If you are using elementor then simply

1. Go to the page
2. Edit with Elementor
3. Open Navigator
4. Click on Video (The one which you want autoplay on)
   5.Now at the right hand side click on "Content"
5. Under the video options select or toggle on Autoplay

Hopefully it helps.

[Elementor navigator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujd2T.png)
[Toogle on option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WMuTq.png)

Comment: Thank you, but with this method, the video will be played at the page loading, not on the scroll.